# "Convert" creates a subfolder "_dirname" when converting .doc

Tags: linux, imagemagick, thumbnails, imagemagick-convert

I try to create thumbnails of every page of a word document (*.doc) on an ubuntu server using "convert", but somehow it creates a subfolder named "_dirname" where it puts a pdf, created out of the doc and then, when trying to create the thumbnails out of that pdf, it can't find the pdf, because it looks in /tmp instead of my work-directory.

```
convert /var/www/test/test.doc /var/www/test/test.png
```

=>

```
convert /tmp/magick-241835c58j2ZyO2oP -> /var/www/test/_dirname/magick-241835c58j2ZyO2oP.pdf using filter : writer_pdf_Export
mv: Error '/tmp/magick-241835c58j2ZyO2oP.pdf' not found
convert: delegate failed `"soffice" --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir `dirname "%i"` "%i" 2> "%Z"; mv "%i.pdf" "%o"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310.
convert: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-24183JEbOOHLGHxoL': File not found @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
convert: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-24183JEbOOHLGHxoL': File not found @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/540.
convert: no images defined `doctest.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

Any ideas how to fix this or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like `soffice` failed. Is `libreoffice` installed?

Comment: Yes, it is installed. Converting the doc to pdf using soffice also works fine.